# Using Tracer For opengl in android debugger

Tags: android, opengl-es, ddms

I am trying to get opengl tracer working for android in monitor. When  I add the name of the app, I am unable to open the app.

It gives me an error Error while launching application : Starting Intent { .... }

And an error saying unable to resolve intent.

Also I do not have access to source code, so is there any way I can get this runnig

Answer (score 4):

I got the answer to it. The problem with it was I was not using the correct activity.

Now to get the name of the activity, I did a

```
adb shell dumpsys activity | grep <name of the application>
```

while focussing over the required activity.

By doing this I got the name of the activity, 
which I used in GLTracer. Once I was able to do so, I could collect trace logs

Comment: I got this: _Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.overdraw/.MainActivity bnds=[176,1037][304,1181] }_. So the name of my Activity to use in GLTracer is `MainActivity` or `.MainActivity`?

Answer (score 3):

It is some tricky to receive Intent name, required for tracer.
You need to type on Android Platform Tools:

```
adb shell dumpsys package <name of application> -f
```

And you will see detailed information about your application,
including Intent name. This Intent name you need to put
into dialog window in GL Tracer plugin (or monitor)

Answer (score 3):

---

From Android N am command have removed --opengl-trace, so you can't use Monitor's OpenGL trace or adb shell am --opengl-trace to debug your APP.
Only use google GPU Debugger gapid.

Answer (score 1):

It can be also this problem [Not Able To Debug App In Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753939/not-able-to-debug-app-in-android-studio) . Check that your application is built as debuggable:

```
<application android:debuggable="true">
</application>
```

I hope, it will help somebody.