# Not Able To Debug App In Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, adb, android-studio

I am making an app in Android Studio, now trying to debug it through adb. When I click on the word Android and the logo on the bottom bar, logcat comes up and recognizes my device. Then I see this:

[image: screenshot]

What do I need to do to my app to make it "debuggable"?

FYI was developing this app in Eclipse before and adb worked fine.

Comment: Uninstalling app from device and run it again from Android studio solved my problem

Comment: I had a problem today, breakpoints cannot stop the program. And It was because of setting in build.gradle. I set debug build type with minifyEnabled is true, remove this and breakpoint worked.

Comment: have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537845/why-android-studio-says-waiting-for-debugger-if-am-not-debugging/51301773#51301773). that might solve the problem

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There is a **Debug** icon on the toolbar. It looks like a little "bug" and is located right next to the **Run** icon (which looks like a play button). Try launching the application with that.

[image: Click here to debug]

Edit: The following is deprecated when using Android Studio with Gradle.

There is also a debug flag in the [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file. It is located under the application tag, and should be set to "true", as follows:

```
<application android:debuggable="true">
</application>
```

Comment: Can we step one line at a time, just like in eclipse ? 
if can, how to do that ?

Comment: Sure you can. Once you hit a breakpoint the debug window is displayed, the toolbar at the top contains the various step commands. You can also configure the various debug keyboard shortcuts from `File` -> `Settings` -> `Keymap` - they are located under `Main menu` -> `Run`. See [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/stepping-through-the-program.html) for more info.

Comment: The latest version of android studio doesn't mandate you to set the android:debuggable, infact it shows an squiggle which suggests to set it in the configuration rather than in the manifest. This helps in avoiding accidently publishing an app with debug information.

Comment: Thanks @Soundararajan for bringing that to my attention. I will update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Not work 2015, build.gradle put buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true

Comment: @delive Is right. I couldn't use my breakpoints until I added that to my build.gradle.

Comment: Using the debug app button as suggested solved the problem.

Comment: it is work for my. I put the in the manifest <application android:debuggable="true">
</application> and debug perfect. Thanks

Comment: That debug button is disabled/greyed.  How do you get it to be clickable?

Comment: Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one

Answer (score 115):

I solved this issue after doing the following steps:

Go to Tools==>android==>Disable ADB integration and enable it again.

After that, unplug USB from device and plug in again.

Finally press shift + F9

Comment: This is what helped me. Suddenly the debug stopped working, after this worked again.

Comment: Stil working  as of today, tried restarting and everything.

Comment: I just needed to close and reopen android studio for that project instance  to make the bug work :/

Comment: Yesterday, while nothing else helped, a reboot did the trick.

Comment: This work for me. Even adb kill-server and  adb start-server commands did not,but it does

Comment: Note for the last part: Shift + F9 is the shortcut to run Debug on Windows. On Mac, it is Control + D.

Comment: Disable and re- Enable ADB Integration helped me on Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: There is no such menu item called "Tools==>android" in Android Studio version 3.1.3 and I cannot find this option anywhere

Comment: In android 3.X I posted an answer that [worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53519263/2829540)

Comment: No "adb" options anywhere in the menus for Android Studio 4

Comment: Use this option to restart ADB in Android Studio 4:  Tools -> "Troubleshoot Device Connection"
Here tap "Next" button. Finally ADB restart option is there in the 4th step

Answer (score 42):

Another thing to be careful of (I did this so I know, duh). Be sure not to enable Proguard for debug!

Comment: thanks and had to make  minifyEnabled false and shrinkResources false

Comment: where to find this ??

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me:

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Open the shell, and write:

   `adb kill-server`

   `adb start-server`

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Previously, I could get this done with a simple `adb reconnect` command, but it doesn't do this anymore in AS 3.1 (maybe I'm doing something wrong, or not enough?

Comment: Btw, this solution worked for me without closing AS, or the terminal session.

Answer (score 23):

```
    <application android:debuggable="true">
</application>
```

This no longer works! No need to use debuggable="true" in manifest.

Instead, you should set the Build Variants to "debug"

[image: Debug Mode]

In Android Studio, go to **BUILD** -> **Select Build Variant**

Now try debugging. Thanks

Comment: The Build menu doesn't have a "Select Build Variant" option.

Answer (score 21):

I also randomly had this problem even after debugging many times in Android Studio. One day the debugger just wouldn't attach. I just had to quit Android Studio and reopen it and the debugger started working again.

Answer (score 13):

If your Application used to be debuggable, and suddenly it's no more debuggable.Here is my solution

1. disable and enable `USB debug` switch in your phone.
2. Uninstall your application.
3. click Run in Android Studio.

Comment: and check "wait for debugger" 2022.10.17. Mac M1 Dolphin

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have enabled the ADB integration.

In Menu: Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB integration 
(v1.0)

Answer (score 9):

This occasionally happens to me and I have yet to figure out why. None of the already posted solutions have worked for me. The only thing that works for me is to:

1. Uninstall application from device.
2. Clean Project. "Build -> Clean Project."
3. Rebuild and install.

Answer (score 8):

One case where you can be unable to debug an application in Android Studio is when you have the "release" build variant selected. Happened to me - Gradle builds a release version of the app (which is not debuggable) and then Android Studio fails at trying to connect the debugger.

Comment: This has tripped me up a number of times, even in other IDEs. I believe the ability to debug release is configurable in most IDEs and sometimes advised if you want to attach the debugger to released apps.

Answer (score 8):

"Attach debugger to Android process" icon shoud be used in case when you set custom "android:process" in your Manifest file. 
In my case I should select suitable process and click OK button just after "Wait for debugger" dialog appears.

[image]

Comment: horrible workaround but the only thing working for me right now, THANKS!!!

Comment: Worked for me even though I did not have a custom "android:process" in my Manifest file.

Comment: this was the solution for me. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In my case near any line a red circle appeared with a cross and red line with a message: "No executable code found at line ..." like in [Android studio gradle breakpoint No executable code found at line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855656/android-studio-gradle-breakpoint-no-executable-code-found-at-line).

A problem appeared after updating of `build.gradle`. We included Kotlin support, so a number of methods exceeded 64K. Problem lines:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
```

Change them to:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
```

Then sync a gradle with a button "Sync Project with Gradle Files". If after restarting of your application you will get an error: "Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K. Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html", then, like in [The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64k API 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785014/the-number-of-method-references-in-a-dex-file-cannot-exceed-64k-api-17) add the following lines to `build.gradle`:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html do the following to enable multidex support below Android 5.0. Else it won't start in these devices.

Open `AndroidManifest` and find tag `<application>`. Near `android:name=` is a reference to an Application class. Open this class. Extend Application class with `MultiDexApplication` so:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

If no Application class set, write so:

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, i forgot minifyEnabled=true and shrinkResources=true in my debug buildType. I change these values to false, it's worked again!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Check, if you're app-project is selected in the drop-down menu next to the debug-button. Sometimes Android Studio just resets this selection...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**If you enable**

```
<application android:debuggable="true">
</application>
```

In the application *manifest.xml* make sure you disable it when generating the final signed apk since this can serve as a security loop hole for attackers. 
Only use it if only one of your applications does not show the logs. However before considering that option try this:

**Navigate to tools in the android studio**

```
 Tools==>android==>disable adb integration and again enable it
```

Answer (score 4):

Restart the adb server, from android studio: Tools -> "**Troubleshhot Device Connection**"

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in Android Studio 3.6.3

> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Android Debug
> Bridge -> Enable 'Use libs backend'

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure you're not using other applications that might be using ADB too, like Eclipse for example.

Answer (score 3):

I tested all ways and non of them worked !!!

finally had to change the adb port and it worked. first kill adb server like below:

```
adb kill-server
```

then restart it using another port

```
adb -P 5038 start-server
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, Had to remove the proguard in debug Build Type by completely clearing the text file `proguard-rules.pro` and making `minifyEnabled false` in build.gradle file

```
  debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to enable developer mode and USB debugging on the device or emulator.  (Easy to forget when setting up a new one.)

Answer (score 2):

You also should have Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration active.

Answer (score 2):

I did clean build using below command.. Surprisingly worked.

> sh gradlew clean build

Hopefully someone get help!

Comment: In which console we have to start it?

Comment: Run this command in the android studio terminal or navigate to your project from external terminal

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it by going to Run -> Edit Configurations, selecting my project, selecting the Debugger tab, then changing 'Debug type' from 'Auto' to 'Dual':[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was trying to debug from a QA build. Change the build variant to Debug and it should work.

To change the build variant, click the menu on the left bottom named "Build Variants"

[image]

In case this menu is not available in your IDE you can do the following.

1. Double click your shift button and you should see a search window popping.
2. Type "Build Variants" as shown below

[image]
3. Now change your build to debug from QA or Release.

Answer (score 2):

**April 2022 :**

all the answers did not help me in **android studio 2022**, I found my solution, maybe help someone else:
I got this error in debug window when I was using `breakpoint` and `debug mode`:

```
Signal: SIGILL (signal SIGILL: illegal instruction) android studio
```

So the solution is:

go to **Run> Edit Configuration > Debugger Tab**
select `Java only` from **debug type**.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem.
Uninstall app from device and run it again via Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it happened when I used Proguard, so by trying all the solutions I cleaned my project and pressed the debug button on Android Studio and it started debugging

Comment: I faced with this issue in android studio 4.1 and your solution helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<application android:debuggable="true">
</application>
```

That above code is not longer a solution. You need to enable debugging inside your build.gradle file. If you have different buildTypes make sure you set "debuggable true" in one of the build types. Here is a sample code from one of my projects.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
    }
}
```

**I have deleted other lines inside the buildTypes which are not relevant to this question from my gradle file here.

Also Make sure you select the correct build variant in your android studio while doing the debugging.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Over the years I have visited this thread many times and there was always a different response that helped me. This time I figure out that it's my USB hub that was preventing debugger to work properly. As strange as it sounds, instead of having a phone connected to my computer via a USB hub, I had to connect it directly to my mac and debugging started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little oops that may catch some: It's pretty easy to accidentally have a filter typed in for the logcat output window (the text box with the magnifying glass) and forget about it. That which will potentially filter out all output and make it look like nothing is there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the same problem because I try to debug signed apk. In my gradle config I made differents build variants, and try to debug release build with production keystore.jks

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in Android Studio 3.2.1

Was:

`RUN -> Attach debugger to Android Process --> com.my app`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My problem was:

1. i was using other debug app apart from my current project in AS.
2. when i click on 'attach to debugger' it was saying "there is no process with com.xyz.abc.appname"

This helped me:
just after 'make project/build' button, there is 'select run/debug configuration' > go to 'Edit configuration'
The configuration is shown in the image.
then my debugger started working.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this not because it's the solution to the question, but I've not seen it anywhere else. If you're running a custom OS and the only debuggable apps listed in Android Studio are the low level ones (probably Qualcomm stuff), you may be debugging as root. If `whoami` within `adb shell` shows your name as `root`, try running `adb unroot`. Your name should now be `shell`. Then try debugging again.

Answer (score 0):

A simple cold boot from device manager menu solved this for my emulator.[image: cold boot menu option]

Answer (score -2):

Sync your project with Gradle files and that shall help.

Comment: don't work. what works was restart adb server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60805797/4628993

Answer (score -3):

I had same problem and I tried almost all kinds of solutions via Google. But I couldn't
solve it. Finally, I found the solution. This is Android Studio Bug.

Do not click `Run` `(Alt + F10)` — just click `Debug` `(Shift + F9)`.

Then Android Studio will show you the Warnning Message with ADB, Then Just click "OK".

You can see log in logcat console. And Packages will be shown on DDMS(Devices).