# Can't attach Android Studio's debugger to Android process

Tags: android, macos, debugging, android-studio, adb

I can't attach Android Studio's debugger to my debuggable application process. Anyone else had this issue? Basically I can't get my app listed in `Choose Process` dialog.

I'm selecting `Attach debugger to Android process`:

[image: Attach debugger to Android process]

And then, here's how `Process selection` dialog from Android Studio looks like:

[image: No app is in the list to be debugged]

Any ideas why my app is not shown in the `Choose Process` list?

Although, `DDMS` sees my app in `Devices | logcat` list:

[image: <code>Devices | logcat</code> list]

`Android Monitor` also sees the app in `Devices` list:

[image: Android Monitor | Devices list]

I've tried these actions:

- Restarting `MacBook`
- Restarting devices: tried with `Samsung Galaxy Note II N7100` (4.3) and `Samsung Galaxy S4` (4.4.2)
- Reenabling `Settings->Developer Options` on the devices
- Reenabling `Settings->Developer Options->USB debugging` on the devices
- Restarting `adb` by running `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`
- Reconnecting device from macbook and/or plugging to another USB port
- Launching Genymotion virtual device on macbook
- `restarting in TCP mode port: 5555` by running `adb tcpip 5555` and then connecting to it with `adb connect 192.168.1.87`
- `Waiting more`&`Restart` when got this error saying `ADB not responding. You can wait more, or kill "adb" process manually and click 'Restart'` `Errors in ADB:` `ddms: '$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary` [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWEdv.png)

**Update:**

What I've noticed is that device appears multiple times in the `Android DDMS`->`Devices | logcat` list. If I choose 1st device from the list, it shows, there's `No debuggable applications`, but I select last device (4th in the screenshot) I see my debuggable application. See screenshots: [1st](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syqo8.png) and [4th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Etm.png). Although, even there's only 1 device in the list and showing debuggable device and application, process still does not appear in the `Choose Process` dialog.

Comment: Check this: [Similar Question answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753939/not-able-to-debug-app-in-android-studio/35230655#35230655)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

So finally I got it working, by:

```
Checking 'Show all processes' checkbox!
```

**BUT** as you see in the question, checkbox was on at the beginning, so there were multiple issues.

To summarize, these are other actions to be done:

- Kill all `adb` processes (use `ps -x | grep adb` and `kill -9 [process id]`)
- `adb start-server` in terminal
- Reconnect device
- `adb devices` (to make sure device is connected successfully)
- Make sure `Android DDMS` `Devices | logcat` shows your app and [only one device is listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wZw7.png).
- Check `Show all processes` checkbox. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRnAH.png)

Comment: Sorry but this is not the solution.  As you mentioned, the box was checked at the beginning.  If your process isn't in the list when the box is unchecked, it's not the process of the running app.

Comment: Make sure that Eclipse and ADT are not open when you are trying to debug with Android Studio.

Comment: I am tired and older than ever closing and reopening things to fix them up all over again. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me on OSX (Mojave) with IntelliJ (2018.3) when adb *could* see my phone but IDE *would not* show it on the list to connect to for debugging. 1) make sure your project has the android facet, 2) shutdown intellij, 3) `adb kill-server`, 3) restart intellij..  this will allow intellij to start the adb server which seems to do the trick for me.

Comment: killing adb by terminal worked for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: I had the same problem, but I'm using Windows.
I just restarted the Android Studio and it solved the problem.

Comment: `adb kill-server && adb start-server` did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

I solved this way

a. Closed Android Studio
b. Did `adb kill-server` from a terminal. Also check the adb process in also killed from the Running processes window in PC
c. Started Android Studio
d. Android Studio tried to initialize adb again and back to work.

Comment: I had to close and restart Android Studio (Mac) and then check "Show all processes" to get the process to appear.

Answer (score 22):

I solved this by going to a terminal and doing:

- `adb kill-server`
- `adb start-server`

Then I clicked in the "attach debugger" button and I could use it as normal

Answer (score 13):

It could be because the `release` build variant (which you can set in the `Build-Variants` section) has been chosen mistakenly, only `debug-variant` is `debuggable`.

Hope this can be helpful to some friends.

Comment: This was indeed the cause of my problem when trying to run on an emulator.  I had to discover it from having another problem trying to run debug on a physical device, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33219069/2848676

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me and its simple,
go to Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration, click on this and mark it selected if not selected this will allow your genymotion instance to connect to ADB but if this doesnt work then, if above mentioned setting is selected then mark unselected and wait till ADB is refreshed( few seconds) then again go to same setting and click on it to mark is selected, this will restart ADB and connect it. This works perfect for me each time i see this issue.

Answer (score 2):

same did happen with me, the root cause for this problem  was  interruption(network disconnection or force close)  while updating any of the plugin(in my case kotlin)
**Solution**
**For mac:**
goto prefrences(shortkey: **cmd** + **,**) 
[image: here is Image of it]

**For windows:(short key:  **ctrl** + **alt** + **s**)
or through menu
[image: here is image of it]

then in left panel look for Languages and Frameworks -> kotlin/java updaes 
and upon selecting it. In right pan there will be option(button) to update the plugin.
update the plugin.
[image: here is image of it]

Exit and Restart the android studio.
now you will be able to debug with all list of available processes running.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this one as well. I was pulling my hair out and did everything that was posted here. I thought I could add to the solutions here in case everyone had tried everything. I solve it via making my build variant debuggable.

So I made a PR and it was merged, unfortunately my debuggable flag on my own build variant was turned off when I pulled the source back, so I just have to turn it back on:

on your build.gradle file:

```
android {
   ...
   buildTypes {
      ...
      my_build_type {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true    // was false before  
      }
   }
}
```

Also make sure that this build variant was set before you build your app to the device:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Close the Android Studio.
2. Kill the adb from terminal 'adb kill-server'. Open android studio ,then attach the debugger. You will be able to see your project.

Comment: in my case, I only had to `adb kill-server`

Comment: I don't think you need to close Android Studio, but it did work for me. Just used the Android Studio terminal to run `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to close android studio as I have seen many advise, you can use the terminal from here. 
In this way :
1 Go to the terminal in Android studio;
2 Did adb kill-server to kill the process;
3 Did adb start-server to running here
4. Check if the devices is attached with adb devices

Now it should work !

Answer (score 1):

In my case I **just plug out and plug in cable from phone.**
Process was listed, and i was able to attach debugger

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all answers before,
If you add breakpoints that evaluate and log,
may be one of them cause Null Pointer exception.
So go to run -> viewBreakpoints... -> unselect all of them.

Answer (score -1):

It might not be a solution, but I eventually just switched to using an emulator device (Nexus 5), instead of a physical device.

I tried everything mentioned above, which includes:

- adb commands
- android studio upgrade, restart, etc
- build variants
- plug in and out the cable.