# Android Studio doesn't see Android processes

Tags: android, macos, debugging, android-studio, in-app-purchase

I apologize for my English.
I can't attach debugger to process, which I run on my device.
I'm selecting **Run->Attach debugger to Android process.** Then I check **Show all processes** in **Choose process** window, but the processes are not there. My device is identified correctly.

I'm also checking **DDMS->Devices** in **Android Device Monitor**. Processes are not there, although my device is identified correctly, and pie Chart on **System Information** tab display "CPU load" information about all device's processes.

I'm trying:

- Restarting my Mac;
- Restarting my device (I have Meizu M2 Note, Android 5.1(API 22);
- Reenabling **Settings->Developer Options->USB debugging** on the device
- Restarting adb by running adb kill-server and adb start-server

I use Android Studio 1.2.2.
I read the similar post [Can't attach Android Studio's debugger to Android process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285999/cant-attach-android-studios-debugger-to-android-process), but my post a little about other. I can't see processes even in DDMS.

General problem is the following: I can't test In-app Purchasing. If I test it in debug-mode on my Mac, Google Play does not make a purchase. But if I install application as alpha-tester from Google Play, and run it on device, debugger can't see this application.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use android studio 1.3 stable release

Comment: I upgrade Android Studio to 1.3 stable release, but nothing changed. Processes no here nor there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a cheat, but I solve my problem.

So, I open my project and go to **Run->Edit Configurations…**
I create a new configuration, wherein choose: «Do not deploy anything» in the **Package** area, «Do not launch Activity» in the **Activity** area, «USB device» in the **Target Device** area. I acted according to the [document](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-and-debugging-android-applications.html).
Then I choose my run/debug configuration, install logcat’s settings like **Log level**: "Error", **find**: {My own TAG}, **rightmost filter**: "Show only selected application".

*Yes, my logs are on Error level. I still have not solved the problem with the spamming logs. Disabling by the `^(?!Surface)` doesn't help, but that is another question.*

Finally I run application on **my** device.

Logcat still doesn’t see the running process, but correctly displays its logs.
Perhaps this helps someone else.