# Unable to debug in android studio (Error running app: java.lang.Error : no Connectors loaded. Check your JDK installation.)

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I am using Android studio 1.02 on Linux Mint. I was able to successfully debug my code on android emulators and my device LG G2 till yesterday. Today when I started my workstation I cant 'debug' my code.

It says:

> Error running navigationbar: java.lang.Error : no Connectors loaded.
>   Check your JDK installation.

On my device I can see the message:

> Waiting for the Debugger
>
> Application NavigationBar (com.example.test.navigationbar) is
>   waiting for the debugger to attach.

and following are the console messages

> Waiting for device. Target device: lge-lg_My_DEVICE'sID
>   Uploading file    local path:
>   /path-to-apk/apk/navigationbar-debug.apk
>     remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.test.navigationbar
>   Installing com.example.test.navigationbar DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm
>   install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.test.navigationbar" pkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/com.example.test.navigationbar Success
>
> Launching application:
>   com.example.test.navigationbar/com.example.test.navigationbar.NavigationBar.
>   DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n
>   "com.example.test.navigationbar/com.example.test.navigationbar.NavigationBar"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.example.test.navigationbar/.NavigationBar }
>
> Waiting for process: com.example.test.navigationbar Can't start
>   debugging.

As advices on some older posts. I have already tried :

1. android:debuggable="true"
2. Restarting android studio and my PC
3. Uncheck and then select again  'Enable ADB integration'
4. Try to debug on emulator(gives the same problem)
5. Make a new program from the android-studio's templates and try to debug it

**On the other hand if I 'run' my application. It gives no such error.**

Finally, if I run android.sh form my terminal then I get this message after I choose my device:

> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector:
>   Provider com.sun.tools.jdi.SunCommandLineLauncher could not be
>   instantiated java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector: Provider
>   com.sun.tools.jdi.RawCommandLineLauncher could not be instantiated
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector:
>   Provider com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketAttachingConnector could not be
>   instantiated java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector: Provider
>   com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketListeningConnector could not be instantiated

Kindly advice steps to resolve this issue.
Thanks

Some links I already tried:

1. [Not Able To Debug App In Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753939/not-able-to-debug-app-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I uninstalled my JDK8 and installed JDK7 this time.
Then if I open Android-Studio. It gave the errors that 'jdk8 not found'.
Upon this I typed :

> rm -R -f ~/.AndroidStudio/

To delete all the settings related to Android-Studio.
Now when you run Android studio it will ask you to install/initialize it again.

That worked for me!!
Note: Till now I was working comfortably with JDK8. Only today due to some change I got the error.