# When I debug my app, I can't look logcat in AS. Following is the error output

Tags: android

When I debug my app, I can't look logcat in AS. Following is the error output.

```
06-02 18:20:55.861 7319-7319/org.zy.app W/Zygote: mz_is_rooted false
06-02 18:20:55.861 7319-7319/org.zy.app I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-02 18:20:55.886 7319-7333/org.zy.app I/art: Debugger is no longer active
06-02 18:20:56.061 7319-7344/org.zy.app I/HAL: (hw_get_module_by_class[194]):MODULE load start ==> class_id = gralloc // path = /system/lib/hw/gralloc.exynos5.so 
06-02 18:20:56.066 7319-7344/org.zy.app I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-02 18:20:56.111 7319-7344/org.zy.app I/HAL: (hw_get_module_by_class[194]):MODULE load start ==> class_id = gralloc // path = /system/lib/hw/gralloc.exynos5.so 
06-02 18:26:22.646 7319-7333/org.zy.app I/art: Debugger is no longer active
```

Comment: I don't understand this cryptic error either, but you could try some of the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753939/not-able-to-debug-app-in-android-studio

Comment: @cs_yale, there is an attribute in the manifest file. 
 android:debuggable=, check the value. It is possible that this might be false, if that is the case, then set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

Click line -fold line like this- edited (delete time and uid and package only error) -ok