# Android Studio: no executable code found at line X on every line

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Every breakpoint I place, not matter what's on the line, is giving the error "no executable code found at line X". I have not changed anything since the last time I was able to debug. I experienced this yesterday but after invalidating caches and restarting, plus restarting my mac, fixed the issue. However today I am having no such luck, I also can't seem to find anyone else having this problem

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591662/cannot-set-java-breakpoint-in-intellij-idea) Or better yet take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855656/android-studio-gradle-breakpoint-no-executable-code-found-at-line/41374114)

Comment: @KlevinDelimeta I've tried this, still not working

Comment: could you try re-creating the project? Also please check Instant Run under settings. That option is evil.

Comment: @KlevinDelimeta instant run truly is evil, I've had it disabled for a long time. Is there a quick way to recreate? This is on a production app with a very large codebase

Comment: I would say Clean->Rebuild, but you already did that. So no. There is no quick way. But it shouldn't take long for you to re-create it like a new project. Re-make the project and build it with Gradle again and hope the problem will go away(which i believe it will). At last, there is this other way, on which you try changing every setting file, but you know, it's not recommended :P.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your gradle

```
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gradle file. It worked for me.

```
debuggable true
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
```