# No executable code found at line inside Observer - Android Studio gradle breakpoint

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to debug inside of a `LiveData Observer` but the debugger says that there is

> No executable code found at line ...

The following screenshot shows what it looks like after I have removed and replaced the breakpoints at the offending lines.

[image: Android Studio breakpoints]

## I have already tried the following:

- The answers on this question: [Android studio gradle breakpoint No
     executable code found at line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855656/android-studio-gradle-breakpoint-no-executable-code-found-at-line)
- removing `.gradle`, `.iml`, `app/build` and `.idea` and restarting
- invalidating caches and restarting
- `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`
- cleaning project and resyncing gradle
- attaching the debugger to the running process again
- uninstalling the app from the device and reinstalling

I am using Android Studio 3.2.1

Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you found solution? I've similar problem, breakpoint at run() method inside Runnable class shows error "No executable code found at line (...) Suspend: thread". And i tried the same ideas as you, without success as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the observer inside the fragment onActivityCreated Method.
After moving code to onCreate method activity, it is started working.