# Instant run is missing in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android

I want to disable instant run but the menu point is not there. I know where the instant run should be, but it is completely missing.  I don't know why. I just upgraded to Android Studio 3.5 but I get an error when using AsyncTask and I know that the problem can be solved when disabling instant run, but I can't.

See the screenshot for better understanding[image: click]

This is my gradle (app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {

            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", GoogleMapDebug
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


        }
           }

    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/asset/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

They removed Instant Run, replacing it with "Apply Changes". See [the release blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/android-studio-35-project-marble-goes.html) for more about the change. And [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes) have more information about the nature of "Apply Changes".

Comment: apply changes only works above android 8, they should bring back instant run for android 5 - 8.

Comment: @CommonsWare How to disable it?

Comment: @voidpointer: I don't see an option to disable it outright. If your concern is the toolbar button, though, you should be able to edit the toolbar and remove it. Right-click on an open area of the toolbar and choose the "Customize" context menu option. Then, search on "Apply".

Answer (score 9):

in version 3.5 it looks like...

[image: like this]

Comment: So, no possibility to disable this?

Comment: @Blnpwr: I did not see one in Settings when I looked for it an hour ago. You should be able to remove those toolbar buttons if they make you concerned, though -- right-click over a open spot in the toolbar and choose "Customize Menus and Toolbars" from the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "Green Arrow" (Run app), Apply Changes will not trigger. And since "Apply Changes" does not alter the generated APKs there is no point "disabling" it.

- If you click Run App, a normal APK is generated, installed and run. Instant Run is not invoked.
- If you click "Apply Changes" or "Apply Code Changes", a normal APK is generated, installed and then Apply Changes triggers via class swapping.

Answer (score 0):

It's here but you need Virtual Device or Smartphone with API 8 or more ... [image]