# No Debugger tab in Edit Configurations (Android Studio 2.3)

Tags: android-studio, debugging

There is an weird issue in my friend's Android Studio 2.3. Normally, we can see the Debugger tab if we go to Run->Edit Configurations. But no Debugger tab shows in his Studio.

[image]

I had tried to re-install to the newest Android Studio 2.3, re-install SDK tools and re-refer to SDK paths. Our environments are almost the same. I can debug, but he can't.

I'm wondering whether the setting for Debugger tab existence was stored under c:\users{user-name}.AndroidStudio2.3 in Windows 10 ? If that's the case, I'm going to uninstall the studio again and delete the folder before re-install.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753939/not-able-to-debug-app-in-android-studio) to this, but intrinsically they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got triumph finally. After uninstalling existing studio and killing those .android & .AndroidStudio2.3 folders, then I re-install studio again. Now the Android studio behaves normally.